# Sending date and time as a TCP server welcome message

Tags: c, sockets, server, tcp

I have to insert this code:

```
time_t ticks = time(NULL);
snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%.24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));
```

to change the message displayed when someone connect to the server, from "Hello student!\n" to the current time and date, but I don't know where copy those two lines of code in the program and what I have to modify in the code after copying those two lines.

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>   
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h> 

const char MESSAGE[] = "Hello student!\n";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int simpleSocket = 0;
    int simplePort = 0;
    int returnStatus = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in simpleServer;
    
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    simpleSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (simpleSocket == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create a socket!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Socket created!\n");
    }

    /* retrieve the port number for listening */
    simplePort = atoi(argv[1]);

    /* setup the address structure */
    /* use INADDR_ANY to bind to all local addresses  */
    memset(&simpleServer, '\0', sizeof(simpleServer)); 
    simpleServer.sin_family = AF_INET;
    simpleServer.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    simpleServer.sin_port = htons(simplePort);

    /*  bind to the address and port with our socket  */
    returnStatus = bind(simpleSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&simpleServer,sizeof(simpleServer));

    if (returnStatus == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Bind completed!\n");
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind to address!\n");
        close(simpleSocket);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* lets listen on the socket for connections      */
    returnStatus = listen(simpleSocket, 5);

    if (returnStatus == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot listen on socket!\n");
        close(simpleSocket);
        exit(1);
    }

    while (1)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in clientName = { 0 };
        int simpleChildSocket = 0;
        int clientNameLength = sizeof(clientName);

        /* wait here */
        simpleChildSocket = accept(simpleSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&clientName, &clientNameLength);

        if (simpleChildSocket == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot accept connections!\n");
            close(simpleSocket);
            exit(1);
        }

        /* handle the new connection request  */
        /* write out our message to the client */
        write(simpleChildSocket, MESSAGE, strlen(MESSAGE));
        close(simpleChildSocket);
    }

    close(simpleSocket);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A little introduction: about the original program

The program starts creating a socket and setting it to listen to a specific port, passed as an argument to your program with a command line such as `programName <port>`.

The port number is retrieved with the line `simplePort = atoi(argv[1]);`. There could have been a stricter check on the parameter (`atoi()` doesn't check if a number is actually provided), but I suppose it is ok for an entry level educational program.

---

After that, with the line

```
simpleChildSocket = accept(simpleSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&clientName, &clientNameLength);
```

the `accept()` function blocks until a connection request from a TCP client is received. As soon as the TCP handshake is completed (`SYN` / `SYN-ACK` / `ACK`, it is
called *three-way handshake*) a socket handle is returned (in your case `simpleChildSocket`) and that can be used to exchange data with the client.

---

### The welcome message

After the accept is completed, and we are sure that all went fine, we soon come to our welcome message. With the lines

```
/* write out our message to the client */
write(simpleChildSocket, MESSAGE, strlen(MESSAGE));
```

the characters contained in the `MESSAGE` string (defined with the constant `const char MESSAGE[] = "Hello student!\n";`) are sent through [`write()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/write) function. Its parameters are

- the socket descriptor
- the pointer to the buffer to be sent
- the number of bytes to be sent (in this case it corresponds to the length of `MESSAGE`, calculated with `strlen(MESSAGE)`

**Note:** `write` function can actually be used, but it is an unconventional choice. In fact it is a *general* function but when writing to sockets [`send()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/send) is actually used.

---

### How to achieve you goal

All you have to do is to substitute `MESSAGE` in the `write()` call with the string containing the date:

```
{
    char buff[30+1];
    time_t ticks = time(NULL);
    snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%.30s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));

    /* write out our message to the client */
    write( simpleChildSocket, buff, strlen(buff) );
}
```

Don't forget to define your `buff` character buffer. I defined it locally but you can also allocate it dynamically.

The code provided by your teacher copies the time calculate with [`ctime()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime) in the `buff` array (I increased its size in order to make sure that the whole *datetime* can be contained in it).

Then we call `write` as we previously did, just substituting `MESSAGE` and `strlen(MESSAGE)` with the new string `buff` and `strlen(buff)`.

Comment: This is not the answer i asked for.
I asked for putting those two lines in the code to fit good and not to change all the code.
But thanks

Comment: @ema I did not change all the code I changed just those two lines. I sorry you didn't like my answer as I put a lot of effort in some explanation of your code and your problem.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I read the message again and I misunderstood the first time i've read it. Sorry

Comment: @Ema It's OK. I hope it helps to understand also what all the program does and not only just the two lines need for your homework. ;)

Comment: Yes it helps a lot, thank you very much.
I really apreciate, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>   
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h> 

/*const*/ char MESSAGE[100] = "";
char buff[100];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int simpleSocket = 0;
    int simplePort = 0;
    int returnStatus = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in simpleServer;
    
    if (argc != 2) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);

    }

    simpleSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (simpleSocket == -1) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create a socket!\n");
        exit(1);

    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Socket created!\n");
    }

    /* retrieve the port number for listening */
    simplePort = atoi(argv[1]);

    /* setup the address structure */
    /* use INADDR_ANY to bind to all local addresses  */
    memset(&simpleServer, '\0', sizeof(simpleServer)); 
    simpleServer.sin_family = AF_INET;
    simpleServer.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    simpleServer.sin_port = htons(simplePort);

    /*  bind to the address and port with our socket  */
    returnStatus = bind(simpleSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&simpleServer,sizeof(simpleServer));

    if (returnStatus == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Bind completed!\n");
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind to address!\n");
    close(simpleSocket);
    exit(1);
    }

    /* lets listen on the socket for connections      */
    returnStatus = listen(simpleSocket, 5);

    if (returnStatus == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot listen on socket!\n");
    close(simpleSocket);
        exit(1);
    }

    while (1)

    {

        struct sockaddr_in clientName = { 0 };
    int simpleChildSocket = 0;
    int clientNameLength = sizeof(clientName);

    /* wait here */

        simpleChildSocket = accept(simpleSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&clientName, &clientNameLength);

    if (simpleChildSocket == -1) {

            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot accept connections!\n");
        close(simpleSocket);
        exit(1);

    }

    /* handle the new connection request  */
    /* write out our message to the client */
    
    time_t ticks = time(NULL);
    snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%.24s\r\n", ctime(&ticks));
    strcpy(MESSAGE, buff);
    write(simpleChildSocket, MESSAGE, strlen(MESSAGE));
        close(simpleChildSocket);
    }

    close(simpleSocket);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Your solution is basically what I suggested in my answer,  but I suggest you to check my solution. In fact you perform an unnecessary copy of `buff` to `MESSAGE`. You can directly send buff (or pass MESSAGE to ctime).

Comment: I forgot to say that the exercise wanted us to use a buffer, sorry

Comment: `buff` IS a buffer. :)